# Locale from E-Mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

Is there a possibility to get the Locale from an E-Mail?

I am using Javax.Mail.Message and want to send automatic responses to the mail user, in the language the user sent the mail.

Is there something like:

```
Locale locale = (Locale)message.getHeader("Locale");
```

Or is there another **easy and simple** way to do get the Locale from a mail=

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the charset header from the received message, and you can then use method [setText(String text, String charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#setText%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)  from MimeMessage

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the [Accept-Language header from RFC 4021](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4021#page-19).  As described in the document there are some pitfalls with using it.  Otherwise, you can use the `MimeMessage.getContentLanguage()` method to check the Content-Language header.